# Java math.random won't randomize inside a function?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, math, random

Got into a start up as a business analyst but I need to learn Javascript for some other tasks in the job :/ I just started using code academy so my knowledge of Javascript is still so limited.

Anyway, I'm trying to produce a random number within a function, but it seems that the number it produces is always the same number/result.

```
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
function getChoice ()
{
  if (randNum) = 0) {console.log("Choice 1")}
  else if (randNum = 1) {console.log("Choice 2")}
  else (console.log("Choice 3")}
}
getComputerChoice()
console.log(randNum)
```

The code seems to always go to choice 2. When I // choice 2 however, it goes to choice 3. For some reason it can't show choice 1. I have also tried to just use the randNum variable for the last console.log(randNum) line to check if it really randomizes. It does, but only when it is not used together with the function

```
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
function getChoice ()
{
  var choiceRandNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
  if (choiceRandNum) = 0) {console.log("Choice 1")}
  else if (choiceRandNum = 1) {console.log("Choice 2")}
  else (console.log("Choice 3")}
}
getChoice()
console.log(randNum)
```

For the code above, I tried making a different variable for the function (but the same sa randNum essentially). Now the last line can show different numbers (0,1,2) but the function still doesn't randomize. Any edits that can be made? Please don't use overly complex solutions as I still don't know a lot of java.

Comment: This looks like javascript and not java.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, javascript is what it says on code academy

Comment: Also, you randomise outside the function, so it only happens once. It's like [that joke](https://xkcd.com/221/). You did the same thing - you just didn't roll the dice but ask the computer to do so - but you still always give out the same predetermined "random number". Put your first line inside the function to see the difference when you actually roll the die every time you need a random number.

Comment: Hi Amadan,      
Not sure I understand. So I have to include var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3) into the first line of the function? I have done that as well but it seems to still produce the same predetermined choice 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are multiple errors in your code. Here's how to fix each of them programatically, starting with your original code and ending with what I believe you want:

1: You have a lot of syntax errors in your code. To start, here's a clean version so it's easier to see what's happening:

```
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
function getChoice() {
if (randNum) = 0) {
  console.log("Choice 1")
}
else if (randNum = 1) {
  console.log("Choice 2")
}
else (console.log("Choice 3")
}
}
getComputerChoice()
console.log(randNum)
```

Then, you can remove all the extra brackets, and add the other brackets:

```
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
function getChoice() {
    if (randNum = 0) {
        console.log("Choice 1")
    }
    else if (randNum = 1) {
        console.log("Choice 2")
    }
    else {
        console.log("Choice 3")
    }
}
getComputerChoice()
console.log(randNum)
```

Finally, you can add equivalence operators `==` instead of assignment operators `=` to your `if` statements, and add semicolons:

```
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
function getChoice() {
    if (randNum == 0) {
        console.log("Choice 1");
    }
    else if (randNum == 1) {
        console.log("Choice 2");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Choice 3");
    }
}
getComputerChoice();
console.log(randNum);
```

2: Your function is named differently to what you're calling. Rename your function to `getComputerChoice()`:

```
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
function getComputerChoice() {
    if (randNum == 0) {
        console.log("Choice 1");
    }
    else if (randNum == 1) {
        console.log("Choice 2");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Choice 3");
    }
}
getComputerChoice();
console.log(randNum);
```

3: You're only declaring the random number once, so it'll never change no matter how many times you call the function. To fix this, declare `randNum` as `0` outside the function, then change it in the function:

```
var randNum = 0;
function getComputerChoice() {
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    if (randNum == 0) {
        console.log("Choice 1");
    }
    else if (randNum == 1) {
        console.log("Choice 2");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Choice 3");
    }
}
getComputerChoice();
console.log(randNum);
```

And now your code will work. Here's a working snippet:

```js
var randNum = 0;
function getComputerChoice() {
  randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  if (randNum == 0) {
    console.log("Choice 1");
  } else if (randNum == 1) {
    console.log("Choice 2");
  } else {
    console.log("Choice 3");
  }
  console.log(randNum);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getComputerChoice()">Random Number</button>
```

Note: The snippet I've provided places the `console.log(randNum)` inside the function, so if `randNum == 1`, the output will be:

```
Choice 2
1
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes it much clearer. Also making randNum = 0 outside the function, ill keep that in mind next time I encounter something similar!

Answer (score 1):

You declare the variable outside the function, so no matter how often you call the function, the outcome will remain the same. You also have some syntax errors in your code. Use `===` instead of `=` and remove some parentheses:

```
function getChoice () {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

    if (randNum === 0) {
        console.log("Choice 1");
    } else if (randNum === 1) {
        console.log("Choice 2");
    } else { 
        console.log("Choice 3");
    }
}

getChoice();
```

This should give you the desired result